# Is every separable algebra in a modular tensor category Morita equivalent to a commutative one?

Tags: fusion-categories, morita-equivalence, modular-tensor-categories, frobenius-algebras, separable-algebras

Separable algebras in modular tensor categories are interesting algebraic structures, which have received significant attention because of their connection to conformal field theories. My understanding is that it is only the Morita class of the algebra which is important for determining the conformal field theory. Also, in the more general case of a fusion category, it is known by a result of Ostrik that up to Morita equivalence, separable algebras correspond to module categories for the fusion category.

Over ordinary vector spaces, every separable algebra is Morita equivalent to a commutative one, which of course makes the Morita equivalence classes easier to study. So this motivates my question: is every separable algebra in a modular tensor category Morita equivalent to a commutative one? If not, what about restricting to symmetric separable algebras?

I am working always over $\mathbb{C}$ here, and assuming that the categories involved are semisimple and with a finite number of isomorphism classes of simple objects.

Comment: You must be assuming that we are working over an algebraically closed field. The quaternions are a separable algebra over the reals, but they are not Morita equivalent to a commutative algebra.

Comment: Yes, MTCs and fusion categories are usually taken to be over $\mathbb{C}$ by defintion, and I was assuming this---I will edit the question to clarify this point.

Comment: I'm not sure about your second question, since symmetric is pretty restrictive.  You can't get a counterexample from su(2).  It seems implausible to me that the answer could be yes, but it also might be hard to find a counterexample.

Comment: One good reason to be interested in the symmetric case is that this is what is relevant for the FRS description of RCFT.

Comment: It is necessary that the modular invariant is of type I, if this helps

Comment: There are even examples of algebras, which give a type I modular invariant and are not Morita equivalent to a commutative algebra, see Ostriks answers here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131906/example-for-non-equivalent-rational-full-cfts-with-same-modular-invariant-parti

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no.  The category of modules over a commutative algebra has a tensor category structure such that the forgetful functor is a tensor functor, but the category of modules over noncommutative algebras need not.  Since the category of modules is a Morita invariant this gives a negative answer.  The usual name for this kind of situation is "Type II modular invariant" and the D_odd module categories over su(2) at roots of unity are the simplest examples.  See [Kirillov-Ostrik](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101219) for more details on everything in this paragraph.  In these examples you have a copy of super vector spaces inside su(2) at a root of unity and the algebra is the anti-symmetric one.

("Morally" super vector spaces with the group ring of Z/2 with each group element supported in its grade is the simplest answer to your question, but technically it's not modular.  But you can find it inside modular categories.)

It is worth noting that module categories over a modular tensor category do have a classification in terms of commutative algebras.  Namely, you pick two commutative algebras A and B plus a braided equivalence between $\mathrm{Rep}^0(A)$ and $\mathrm{Rep}^0(B)$.  This is proved in [Davydov-Nikshych-Ostrik Cor 3.8](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5558), though the idea goes back at least to Ocneanu.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer. I am having difficulty pushing this argument through my brain. Suppose I have a commutative monoid object $A$ in a modular tensor category, and module actions $f:A \otimes X \to X$ and $g:A \otimes Y \to Y$. How are you defining the tensor product module? The only way I know how to do it is if $A$ is equipped with a bialgebra structure.

Comment: I am also confused for another reason: I thought separable algebras have semisimple module categories. Are you saying there's a semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-linear category that does not admit a monoidal structure? That would stun me. Surely I have missed something here.

Comment: You're tensoring over A, not over the base field.  It's just like how modules over an ordinary commutative algebra form a tensor category.  For more details see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101219

Comment: Hopefully my edit clarified your second question.  The issue is whether the module category has a tensor product that's compatible with the module category structure.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify which algebra you have in mind in super vector spaces. Do you mean the exterior algebra on $I \oplus F$, where $F$ is the fermion? I don't see that this is separable.

Comment: There's a forgetful functor from SVec to Vec, so internal endomorphisms of the 1-dimensional vector space gives a 2-dimensional algebra in SVec.  Since Vec is semisimple this is separable.  Indeed it's $1 \oplus F$ and there's only one algebra structure on it.

Comment: I don't know what an 'internal endomorphism' is unfortunately. I think there are at least 2 algebra structures on $I \oplus F$ in SVec. Write $1$ and $f$ for the vacuum and fermion basis elements respectively: then one algebra has $f^2 = 1$, and the other has $f^2 = 0$. The first of these is separable and non-commutative, and the second is non-separable and commutative.

Comment: Good point.  Yes, I meant the former.

Comment: Great, so now I understand. I also see what you mean by internal endomorphism.

Comment: Having played with this for 10 minutes, I cannot construct a non-free module for this algebra---can you put me out of my misery?

Comment: The module category is Vec, so there are no non-free modules for that algebra.

Comment: It's worth noting that A being commutative corresponds to mod-A being an E_2-module category over C.  Part of being an E_2-module category is being a tensor category in a compatible way, but another part is additional compatibility in the braiding.  My first paragraph is about situations where the first part breaks, but for this SVec example the first part is fine but it's still not a commutative algebra (by inspection) and so it's the second part that fails.