# Is there an E8 symmetry in the zero-field Ising model?

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups, conformal-field-theory

In the paper [On classification of modular tensor categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1377) by Rowell, Stong and Wang, they list the Ising modular category $I$ as having 3 objects $1$, $\sigma$ and $\psi$, with fusion rules $\sigma^2 = 1 + \psi$, $\sigma \psi = \psi \sigma = \sigma$ and $\psi^2 = 1$. There are in fact 16 modular tensor categories with these fusion rules (see [DGNO](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0620), App B). What distinguishes $I$ from the rest is that in $I$, if I understand correctly, the dimension of $\sigma$ equals $\sqrt{2}$ (as opposed to $-\sqrt{2}$) and that the twist $\theta_\sigma = e^\frac{\pi i}{8}$ (as opposed to some other eighth root of $-1$).

RSW say that that `$I$ can be obtained as a quantum group category as the complex conjugate of $E8$ at level = 2'.

Is this just a coincidence? Or is there some kind of straight-up $E8$ symmetry in the underlying statistical mechanical Ising model, at zero magnetic field?

I'm aware of the Zamolodchikov $E8$ symmetry that apparently arises when one perturbs the zero-field Ising model to have a magnetic field (see [this](http://www.garibaldibros.com/linked-files/Borthwick-Garibaldi-E8.pdf) article, and these previous math overflow posts [A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32315/has-the-lie-group-e8-really-been-detected-experimentally), [B](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32432/does-the-quantum-subgroup-of-quantum-su-2-called-e-8-have-anything-at-all-to-do)). Perhaps it is related? But I'm talking about an $E8$ symmetry that somehow shows up already in the zero-field case (i.e. in the conformal field theory, since the perturbed theory is not a conformal field theory).

Comment: All the 16 modular tensor category with Ising fusion rules can be made unitary (so $d_\sigma=\sqrt{2}$) and the difference is only the twist. This MTC can be represented as conjugate of $(E_8)_2$, or the conjugate of $SO(15)_1$, so I doubt it has anything to do with the $E_8$ symmetry of Zamolodchikov.

Comment: Your first statement isn't right; it's easy to get confused in this business. See [DGNO App B](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0620). There are two spherical structures for each Ising fusion category. In one spherical structure, $\dim \sigma = \sqrt{2}$, in the other, $\dim \sigma = -\sqrt{2}$. "Making it unitary" has the effect of selecting a preferred spherical structure (the one with positive dimensions). There are only 8 different twists, all of them an eighth root of -1. That is how I arrived at my statement, that the MTC's could be distguished by the sign of dim$\sigma$ and $\theta_\sigma$.

Comment: When you say that the Ising MTC can be represented as the conjugate of $SO(15)_1$, how do you compute that?

Comment: First of all every modular tensor coming from a conformal field theory comes from many different conformal field theories. The 8 unitary Ising MTCs are realized for example by Virasoro $c= 1/2$ minimal model, $\mathrm{Spin}(2n+1)_1$ for $n=1,\ldots,7$. The $n=7$ case is apparently also realized by $E_{8,2}$. This CFT has a $E_8$ symmetry.

Comment: See here for the non uniqueness of the realization by a CFT http://mathoverflow.net/q/207325/10718

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the nonuniqueness of realizing an MTC by a CFT. Nevertheless, the fact remains. On the one hand, we have the Ising statistical mechanics model. On the other hand, we have the Ising conformal field theory. I know of three "natural" ways to formulate the CFT: as a minimal model, as the free fermion, or as a coset model, as in [the big yellow book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?lr=&id=keUrdME5rhIC&q=ising+e8#v=snippet&q=ising%20e8&f=false), namely $(\hat{E_8})_1 \oplus (\hat{E_8})_1/(\hat{E_8})_2$. The question remains: is there thus an $E8$ symmetry in the stat-mech model?

Comment: So on the CFT side Virasoro $c=1/2$ cannot have any symmetries. If it had one you could take the orbifold, but Virasoro is minimal.